# Is this the rule for a function to be holomorphic?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, holomorphic-functions

I made up this rule and I think it should work:

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(z+h(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta))-f(z)}{h(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)}$$

If the limit exists and is independent of $\theta$, then the function is holomorphic or differentiable at $z$.

Clearly, fixing a particular value of $\theta$ means approaching $z$ from one particular direction. So, if this limit is independent of $\theta$, then the function has the same derivative from whatever direction we approach it. Is this rule correct?

Comment: Did you try it for $f(z) = z$? For $\theta = 0$, you get $1$; what do you get for $\theta = \pi/2$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I think there's a slight problem. I need some time.

Comment: I agree there's a problem. :)

Comment: @JohnHughes But I'm sure for one thing. For $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we will use $ih$ in the denominator. So, the denominator needs some modification. It will depend upon $\theta$. Can you think of something?

Comment: @JohnHughes I'm not sure but I guess $h(cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ should be in the denomiator.

Comment: The thing is that you have to show that the limit exists for any sequence of complex numbers converging to $0$, but the way you have formulated your definition it only accounts for 'some' of the many possible sequences for which the limit must exist.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(re^{i\theta'}) = \frac{1}{\theta'}r^2$, where $r > 0, \theta' \in (0,2\pi)$.
Check: Your limit for $z=0$ is 0 regardless of the choice of $\theta$, but $f$ is not even continuous at $0$, as $f$ takes arbitrarily large values in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think that $f$ takes arbitrarily large values in the neighbourhood of $0$. Sure, in the neighbourhood of $0$ $\theta'$ will be very small but you're not taking $r^2$ into account. Because $r$ is itself close to $0$ in the neighbourhood of $0$, so $r^2$ will be even more close to $0$, therefore $\frac{r^2}{\theta}$ will actually be close to $0$.

Comment: That's not precise reasoning. Even if r is small,  just let theta = r^2 / some  huge number

Comment: I can say that too for $r$. BTW, the more 'necessary requirement' for a number to be in neighbourhood of $0$ is $r$ should be small, not $\theta$. $0.0000001i$ is in the neighbourhood of $0$ but has $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I think you confuse what I mean by $\theta$. Every non-zero complex number $z$ can be written uniquely as $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $r>0, \theta \in [0,2\pi)$. A neighbourhood basis of $0$ is for instance given by the sets $B(0,R) := \{ z | |z|<R \}$, but the restriction on $|z| = |ze^{i\theta}|=r$ poses just a restriction on $r$, but no restriction on $\theta$, so for every $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and every $R > 0$ you will find that $re^{i\theta} \in B(0,R)$ as long as $r < R$.

Comment: What is $R$? Also, do you mean to say $\theta$ doesn't mean the argument here?  I thought you'd just written a complex function as a function of its modulus $r$ and argument $\theta$. If $\theta$ is the argument, then $\theta\approx 0$ is certainly not the requirement of being in the neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: $\{ B(0,R) \mid R > 0 \}$ is the neighbourhood basis of 0. I have indeed written $f$ as a function in the modulus $r$ and argument $\theta$. You are also right about $\theta$ being close to $0$ not being the requirement of being in some neighbourhood $B(0,R)$ of 0. But the point is this: For any *arbitrarily* small argument $\theta$  there *exists*, in *any neighbourhood* of 0, a complex number $z$ with that argument.

Comment: So you're saying that for some complex numbers in the neighbourhood, $\theta$ is very close to $0$, so the function is arbitrarily large.  You wrote this:'Even if r is small, just let theta = r^2 / some huge number'. I can make that argument for $r$ too. Here, there's a square of $r$, so the square of small $r$ is even more small. But $\theta$ is not squared. I think in the limit, the derivative converges to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56153/discussion-between-long-and-dove).